# ¿Cómo puedo usar la cámara para generar fotos con descripción en una App?

Tags: java, android

Es como una lista (o cola) de fotos, cada una acompañada con una breve descripción.
No sé cómo conectar el XML con Java y sea dinámico...

Comment: Bienvenido Juan, te sugiero que antes que nada vayas a [tour] para saber como funcionamos y de paso ganes tu primera medalla... Después ve a [ask] y por favor edita o elimina tu pregunta según corresponda, ya que la misma está sujeta a puntuaciones negativas y reportes...